# How do I use a custom theme for the WP Maintenance Mode plugin?

Tags: plugins

How do I use a custom theme, rather than the themes included with this plugin?

Here is the link to the plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/

I see that under the plugin's settings there is a way to choose "own style" theme and a way to link to custom stylesheet, but I want to use my own html as well.

Comment: Can we get a link to the plugin and the exact problem you are having? What have yo tried? Please provide more information.

Comment: If this is the plugin you are talking about see the main page for a template/instructions http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to do this is on the front of the plugins wordpress.org page.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/

> You can add your own html and stylesheet and add the url of this style
>   to the options of the plugin. Write your style to this markup and
>   upload to the webspace; after add the url include http:// to the
>   settings of this plugin and change th theme to "Own Theme":

Which while it is ambiguous, the settings page does offer an alternative. If you upload a dedicated maintenance html page, then use the redirect feature to redirect to it, you would have full control over the page.

It may be that this plugins themes are purely CSS based. You may be able to use the hooks and filters provided to remove and add items of content and markup, but redirects are the simplest method.

**edit:** After some talk with the plugin author, I've gotten the readme for the plugin and terminology changed, it seems if you put a `wp-maintenance.php` in wp-content it will use that instead of the default html.

Comment: Of course I saw that on the plugin's homepage. Where you place/link the css is obvious in the plugins settings/options.  But where the HTML goes is not so clear to me.

Comment: hmmm yes, I've raised an issue with the plugin author on github to see if the readme.txt can be further clarified

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative solution, based on the redirect part of the plugin

Comment: Are you referring to WP's built in redirect feature? How would I use this?

Also, where would I place the hooks and filters?

Comment: There's a redirect option in the plugin settings

Comment: updated my answer, it should do as expected now

Comment: Just to clarify (as I stumbled upon this from searching), if you use `wp-maintenance-mode.php` in the WP-Content folder (rather than `wp-maintenance.php` as above), it will override the default template in the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good, but a little outdated. Instead of `wp-maintenance.php` you must instead add `wp-maintenance-mode.php` to one of these directories.

```
/wp-content/
/wp-content/themes/{your_child_theme}/
/wp-content/themes/{your_theme}/
```

Your custom maintenance mode template will load from the `wp-maintenance-mode.php` file.

More info can be found here
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/feature-request-allow-overriding-templates/#post-12025524